# c++ why does ((1 / 2) * 2) return 0

Tags: c++

first time I'v posted here but I must know what's wrong with this simple peace of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double test = (1 / 2) * 2;
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when ever I run this the code it displays 0, should I be casting something, it happens regardless of what compiler I use and it returns even stranger results if the '1' is divided be some form of decimal.

Comment: Because 1 and 2 are `int`s. And by default, all numbers are `int`s.

Comment: In OP's defense, this is really hard to search for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in integer maths `1 / 2 == 0` and `0 * 2 == 0`.

Try with `1.0` and `2.0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In `(1 / 2)` both the 1 and 2 are integers which means that the result is also an integer. This means the expression returns `0`. `0 * 2` is `0`.

To get the result you want, try `(1.0 / 2.0)`

Comment: It's enough to `.0` only one side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get right result you need to write:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double test = ((double)1 / 2) * 2;
  cout << test << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explanation needed. Also it's enough to cast only one side, the other will be implicitly cast.

Comment: Also, don't use C-style casts.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `int` instead of `double`.

Fixing...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double test = (1.0 / 2.0) * 2.0;
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```